# Content Editors can't delete Blog post in 2sxc Blog App 03.03.00

Tags: 2sxc

Users are trying to delete a blog post by clicking the X icon on the toolbar for that post. When they do, nothing happens. When I'm logged in as a superuser, I can delete it just fine. I look at the browser console and can see an error being thrown in the item-command.ts file. The webApi call is context.sxc.webApi.delete(`app-content/any/${itemGuid}`, params, null, true). The request doesn't complete and is caught in the fail callback. The message in the console is "Error: Error in 2sxc Content API - not allowed". Is this a bug or something with security for users? Users were able to delete posts in the blog app before upgrading to 11.22.00. I am not sure how to correct this issue and am looking for some pointers.

Comment: What was your 2sxc version before upgrading to 11.22? What version of Dnn?

Comment: previous version of 2sxc: 8.13 and 9.6.2 Evoq

Answer (score 0):

There were breaking changes to 2sxc around 10.20+, have you examined the errors? They should include line numbers and a terse explanation of what is wrong. In most cases the errors will include extra info about how to fix it. Basically you need to modify the code a little to account for the changes.

Below you can see an example of one of the changes I had to make after upgrading a site with 2sxc 9.x and an old version of the 2sxc FAQs app.

[image]

Comment: Another common one to watch for, if you see code using `ToSic.SexyContent.Environment.Dnn7.Factory...`, you'll need to find examples and that use `ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Factory...` instead.

Comment: Also, if you see errors being throw regarding `ListContent` or `Presentation`, those have been changed, renamed as `Header` and moved to `Content.Presentation`.

Comment: I'll take a look and see if that solves the issue.